# How can I detect multiple keywords in python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu-word, detect

I am looking for a way to create several lists and for the keywords in those lists to be extracted and matched with a responce.

User Input: This is a **good day** I am heading out for **a jog**.

List 1 : Keywords : good day, great day, awesome day, best day.
List 2 : Keywords : a run, a swim, a game.

But for a huge database of words, can this be linked to just the lists? Or does it need to be especific words?

Also would you recommend Python for a huge database of keywords?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is really too broad for us to answer: you'll get better help if your questions are focused on specific issues and include your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to break the input string up into tokens. A token is just a piece of the string that you want to match. In your case, it looks like your token size is 2 words (but it doesn't have to be). You might also want to strip all punctuation from the input string as well.

Then for your input, your tokens are 
    ['This is', 'is a', 'a good', 'good day', 'day I', 'I am', 'am heading', 'heading out', 'out for', 'for a', 'a jog']

Then you can iterate over the tokens and check to see if they're contained in each one of the lists. Might look like this:

```
input = 'This is a good day I am heading out for a jog'
words = input.split(' ')
tokens = [' '.join(words[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(words) - 1)]
for token in tokens:
  if token in list1:
    print('{} is in list1'.format(token))
  if token in list2:
    print('{} is in list2'.format(token))
```

One thing you will likely want to do to optimize this is to use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set)s for list1 and list2, instead of lists.

```
set1 = set(list1)
```

`set`s offer O(1) lookups, as opposed to O(n) for lists, which is critical if your keyword lists are large.